# facebook redirect_uri set to ios URL Scheme

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm starting to investigate how to work with Facebook programmatically.

I've set URL scheme in my app, so that I could open it from browser using "myappopenup://".

Then I created an app in Facebook. Copied an AppId and tried to make like this:

```
let url = NSURL(string: "https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id={MY_APP_ID_WAS_HERE}&redirect_uri=myappopenup://fbcallback")
UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(url!)
```

After running this code, simulator opened safari (I've tried with SFSafariViewController first). but everything I saw was:

[image]

So, I'd like to know: Is it possible to redirect from the Facebook oauth to my app?

Comment: No, it is not. For native mobile apps, you should use the SDKs Facebook provides to handle login.

Comment: You don't have to use the FB SDK for native apps.... In fact, FB bloats their SDK with god knows what, so if you only need login, it's not a bad idea to build your own service.

Answer (score 14):

Yes it is possible. Here's the necessary **redirect_uri**:

```
  https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/authorize
  ?response_type=token
  &client_id='+'1247676148624015
  &redirect_uri=fb1247676148624015://authorize
```

Make sure your facebook app is set up:

[image: Facebook App Setup]

And make sure your custom URL scheme is set up:

[image]

Disappointing comment above -- likely misled many people. This stuff is not well-documented at all, though.

Comment: Just one problem: values like this seem to be rejected as invalid when provided as Valid OAuth redirect URIs in the Facebook Login section on developers.facebook.com. I tried `fb<bundle_id>://authorize`. The error message is "Something went wrong. We're working on getting it fixed as soon as we can." The error code (from the HTTP traffic) is `1357010`, but that code is not documented online.

Comment: This solution doesn't seem to work anymore. Any insight, Alex?

Comment: BTW, you *must* (it seems) use the `authorize` path, you can't use another custom path and expect this to work.  Wasted a couple hours on that detail.

Comment: This didn't work for me either.  I really think that facebook wants you to exclusively use their SDK for this.

Answer (score 2):

I contacted Facebook support and they confirmed that it's not supported:

*Thanks for getting in touch. We'll make the messaging more clear on this, but we do not support custom URI schemes as valid redirect URIs. To perform login in a native app without opening the browser, please use the official SDKs (is https://github.com/xamarin/FacebookComponents what you're looking for?).*

They responded in less that 12 hours, which at least was impressive.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to make [Alex Paterson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4942906/alex-paterson) solution work here. I had to add the redirect_uri URL on Facebook Login settings too. On section **Valid OAuth redirect URIs** I've added the callback URL like this:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/authorize?
response_type=token&
client_id=12345678910&
redirect_uri=fb12345678910://authorize
```

Comment: Do you mean the whole "https://graph.facebook..." url or just the redirect_uri (fb...)?

Comment: @Toshkuuu the whole URL on Facebook Developers config.

Answer (score 0):

As some of the other answers & comments indicate, I don't think that what you're trying to do is supported by Facebook - my impression is that they really want you to use the FBSDK to accomplish authenticating and receiving a token from facebook.

It feels like I've tried every possible configuration under the sun with the `someapp://authorize` strategy, but it really seems likes they only want you to do this for web apps.

I'm building with react native (so this may not directly apply.  I'm sure the obj-C is somewhat similar in practice), so I'm using the `react-native-fbsdk` library which exposes `LoginButton` and `AccessToken` components, and you can use them as such:

```
          <LoginButton
           readPermissions={["email", "public_profile"]}
           onLoginFinished={
            (error, result) => {
             if (error) {
              alert("Login failed with error: " + result.error);
             } else if (result.isCancelled) {
              alert("Login was cancelled");
             } else {
              AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken().then((data) => {
                  const token = data.accessToken;
                  // send the token to your backend
                }
              )
              alert("Login was successful with permissions: " + result.grantedPermissions)
            }
          }
        }
        onLogoutFinished={() => alert("User logged out")}
      />
```