# Why is custom scheme for redirect_uri for facebook login not working?

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, webview

Answer to the question: [facebook redirect_uri set to ios URL Scheme](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38261112/facebook-redirect-uri-set-to-ios-url-scheme)  did not solve my problem.

Trying to implement Facebook login in Android WebView (using Facebook SDK is working, but want to implement it in WebView for some reason):

```
private void launchFacebookOauth() {

    // intent
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, getAuthorizationUri());
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);
    startActivity(intent);
    finish();

}  

public Uri getAuthorizationUri() {

    final String CLIENT_ID = "client_id";
    final String RESPONSE_TYPE = "response_type";
    final String REDIRECT_URI = "redirect_uri";
    final String CODE = "code";


    Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
    params.put(CLIENT_ID, clientId);
    params.put(RESPONSE_TYPE, CODE);
    params.put(REDIRECT_URI, redirectUri);


    Request request = new Request.Builder().url(AUTHORIZATION_ENDPOINT_URL).build();
    HttpUrl.Builder builder = request.url().newBuilder();
    for (Map.Entry<String, String> param : params.entrySet()) {
        builder.addQueryParameter(param.getKey(), param.getValue());
    }
    HttpUrl httpUrl = builder.build();

    return Uri.parse(httpUrl.toString());
}
```

When using scheme: `http://` or `https://` for redirect_uri, Android shows dialog to choose from MyTestApp & browser (don't want this behaviour). So, trying to use custom scheme: `fb12345678` & host `hovermind.com`

```
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
        <data android:scheme="fb12345678" android:host="hovermind.com"/>
    </intent-filter> .
```

> redirect_uri: fb12345678://hovermind.com

Getting error in the WebView:

> Can't Load URL: The domain of this URL isn't included in the app's
>   domain. To be load this URL, add all domains and subdomains of your
>   app to the App Domains field in your app settings .

FYI, `hovermind.com` is added in 'App Domains' section and 'Valid OAuth redirect URIs' section (developers dashboard) .  When trying to add `fb12345678://hovermind.com` in Valid OAuth redirect URIs section, Facebook shows error dialog.

How to laucnh my App using custom redirect_uri scheme from WebView (Facebook login) ?

> Don't want to use `App Links` either ( min. SDK >= 23 and server config issue )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could not find any solution or StackOverflow answer & therefore came to the conclusion that use [Facebook Login for Android](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/android/) instead of WebView